# How to avoid an error of creation a database, with relationship one to many?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

There is a two models, I want to create relationship one to many. Where one user can have some count of tasks.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
}
```

In `Task` model class, I created two navigational properties and two foreign keys that should connect with `User` model class:

```
public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDateTask { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlannedStartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime PlannedCompletionDate { get; set; }
    public bool StartExecution { get; set; }
    public bool IsExecution { get; set; }
    public bool IsDone { get; set; }
    public int? FromUserId { get; set; }
    public int? ToUserId { get; set; }
    public User ToUser { get; set; }
    public User FromUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created a `Users` table by Entity Framework

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [FullName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Users] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And finally I want to create a `Tasks` table, but when I created a script and update I get this error:

> An error occurred while the batch was being executed

This is the script of `Tasks` table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Tasks] 
(
    [Id] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [StartDateTask] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL,
    [PlannedStartDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [PlannedCompletionDate] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    [StartExecution] BIT NOT NULL,
    [IsExecution] BIT NOT NULL,
    [IsDone] BIT NOT NULL,
    [FromUserId] INT NULL,
    [ToUserId] INT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Tasks] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tasks_Users] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([FromUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]) 
           ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Tasks_User] 
        FOREIGN KEY ([ToUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]) 
           ON DELETE SET NULL
);
```

Maybe I have some mistakes in this script?

Comment: Thanks for the correction @marc_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I execute your SQL scripts in SSMS, I get

> Msg 1785, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   'FK_Tasks_User' on table 'Tasks' may cause cycles or multiple cascade
>   paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify
>   other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Msg 1750, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

If I change your

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Tasks_User] FOREIGN KEY ([ToUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]) 
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

to

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_Tasks_User] FOREIGN KEY ([ToUserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id]) 
ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

It creates the table.

I would, however, suggest using [Entity Framework Migrations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591621(v=vs.113).aspx) to generate your SQL

Comment: Thank you @Alex it`s working! And you advised me EF Migrations, but as I know, I have to use Migrations if my model class is changed.